# How to remove or disable " Subject " In Comments Field in Drupal 10

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-8, drupal-9, drupal-comments

**I am using Drupal 10**

I have created a content type (Film Review) & added few fields like Comments & Image.
So When i try to post comments using various roles ( for eg: Anonymous Role ) Comment field is required but whereas subject is not so i left it blank.

So, the issue is it's taking same whatever written in comment  in Subject as well. So it is seen twice in site. I have attached Images for better understanding.

[image: Subject in Comments field]

[image: After Submitting the Comment]

I have tried to uncheck " Subject in comments field " for previous versions it used to in Manage Fields section,but i didn't find the option there with that name.

**Structure> Content Types > Film Review > Manage fields> Comments**

In comments field i didn't found any " subject " to uncheck it.

Any Suggestions Appreciated,Thank you

Comment: Two ideas :

A) Tweak the twig file if possible, B) Hide it using CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always disable comments form fields from form display setting e.g

```
admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/form-display
```

and drag the subject field into disabled section that all.